# Full calendar event limit text on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am using https://fullcalendar.io/ calendar i have used eventLimitText : "more" i want the date on click of eventLimitText

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
header: {
  left: 'prev,next today',
  center: 'title',
  right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
},
eventLimit: true,
timeFormat: 'H:mm',
dayClick: function(date, jsEvent, view) {
  alert('Clicked on: ' + date.format());
```

}
 })

Comment: i want to get **date** on click of **more** text

Comment: By using https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimitClick you can specify any functionality you want to happen when the "more" link is clicked. The callback even provides you with the date information directly. Did you check this documentation yet?

Comment: can you provide jsfiddle for this , thanks in advance

Comment: You can try it for yourself first, and if you get a problem, ask again. It's not hard. The concept is really very similar to what you're doing above with "dayClick". Same idea, just a different callback name and different input parameter structure (but the documentation is very clear about what the structure is, it's very simple to understand if you take a moment to read it). If you try yourself first you'll learn much better than if I just spoon-feed you the code. I'm happy to help you if you actually get stuck with a problem, as opposed to just not having made any effort yet.

Comment: @ADyson i wil try and let you know :)

Comment: @ADyson thanks man it works :)

Comment: Great, glad you solved it. You should add your solution code (and a brief explanation) in the "Answers" section then...you are allowed to answer your own question. Then others can learn from it, and also they can vote on it, which gives you the chance to earn reputation points. So that way everyone wins :-).

Comment: Hi @ADyson yes your suggestion is valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have solved this problem by reading [this documentation](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/eventLimitClick)

Here is the code

```
 $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   header: {
     left: 'prev,next today',
     center: 'title',
     right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },
   eventLimit: true,
   timeFormat: 'H:mm',
   eventLimitClick: function(cellInfo, jsEvent, view) {
     var from_date_val = JSON.stringify(cellInfo.date);
     var from_to_val   = JSON.stringify(cellInfo.date);
   },
});
```

Comment: N.B. since `date` (the inner property I mean) is a momentJS object, you could actually get a more flexible output by using momentJS's [formatting options](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/). e.g. `var from_date_val = date.date.format("DD/MM/YYYY");` would output the date in dd/mm/yyyy format like 14/02/2019. So I don't know if that might be useful to you, rather than relying on JSON.stringify to output a default string.

Comment: P.S. the code might be clearer if you named the initial input parameter in the callback more accurately. e.g. `eventLimitClick: function(cellInfo, jsEvent, view) {` rather than calling it `date`. It does contain the date, in the inner "date" property, but it also contains other things, as you can see in the documentation. For the maintainbility of your code, it might be better to use a more accurate name. `date.date` looks like a mistake at first glance! It's only my opinion, but I've always found it easier to debug or enhance my code later if the meaning of the variables is clear.

Comment: I can't accept the answer. I've upvoted it though. You're the person who asked, so it's you who must accept. It would make no sense for others to accept the answer...only the person asking knows if it was the correct solution for them. Now, because you are both the asker and answerer, you must wait 48 hours before you can accept your own answer - to give others a chance to have a go as well, if they wish to. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer for details.